# Unable to generate Swagger json doc out of my spring code

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-maven-plugin

I installed Swagger-UI as a standlone which being served by nginx server.

We have couple of microservices and I am trying to implement swagger json out of our spring-boot app.

So if I understand it right I need to point at swagger-ui the url to my swagger endpoint of my app in order to receive that json info.

How I did it?

on gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile("com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:0.8.8")
}
```

Added new configuration to my app:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class SwaggerConfig {
    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;
    @Autowired


    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig) {
            this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
        }
        @Bean
    // Don't forget the @Bean annotation
 public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation() {
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig).apiInfo(
                apiInfo()).includePatterns("/saurzcode/.*");
    }
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("SaurzCode API", "API for Saurzcode",
                "Saurzcode API terms of service", "mail2saurzcode@gmail.com",
                "Saurzcode API Licence Type", "Saurzcode API License URL");
        return apiInfo;
    }
    }
```

and added to one of my controllers this:

```
@ApiOperation(httpMethod = "GET", value = "Say Hello To World using Swagger")
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
String get() {
    ...
}
```

Now when I invoke my app with the following url:

http://localhost:8080/api-docs

I get:

```
{"apiVersion":"1.0","swaggerVersion":"1.2","info":{"title":"SaurzCode API","description":"API for Saurzcode","termsOfServiceUrl":"Saurzcode API terms of service","contact":"mail2saurzcode@gmail.com","license":"Saurzcode API Licence Type","licenseUrl":"Saurzcode API License URL"}}
```

How from this point i am generating the right json file and actually having my swagger ui to point at it:

[image]

As soon as I enter any url into the swagger ui I get:

```
Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.
```

I added this in my spring client to enable cors:

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

It solved but:
 if I restart my spring app my browser showing again this error. 
If I use incognito-mode it works again.. something with local cache.. any idea?
Thank you.
ray.

Comment: Have you followed the steps as described here? https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/README.md#cors-support

Comment: Yes. and it worked but if I take my server down and up again my browser brining back this error. if I use incognito-mode it works again.. something with local cache.. any idea?

Comment: Are your microservices behind nginix ? In that case it would be nice to try setting up cors on the nginx itself.

Comment: @EmanueleIvaldi nope only swagger-ui app is being served by nginx